# What is the most network efficient method of fetching a set of rows in HBase?

Tags: java, hbase

Say that I have a set of row keys (as a Set). What is the most network efficient method of fetching a particular column family for this set of rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [HTable.get(List<Get> gets)](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#get%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: Related, is there a way to get all rows _except_ the ones in a given set ?